# Table join and group by in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on a API and I am using resource to return the collection. I am having problem in grouping data. I have following code.

```
return TicketResource::collection(
                Ticket::query()                    
                    ->search(request('search'))
                    ->whereHas(
                        'latestStatus', function($query) use ($request){
                            $query->whereIn('status_id', $request->status)                            
                            ->where(function($inner_query) use ($request){
                                if($request->status === 1){
                                   $inner_query->where( 'tickets.user_id', '!=', auth()->user()->id);
                                } elseif($request->status === 2){
                                    $inner_query->where( 'ticket_statuses.user_id', auth()->user()->id);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    )
                    ->join('ticket_statuses', function($join){
                        $join->on('tickets.id', '=', 'ticket_statuses.ticket_id');
                    })
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($userBrands, $userAppliances, $buyerPurchasedTicket, $buyerexcludedZipCode, $buyerexcludedDevices) {
                        $query->whereIn('appliance_id', $userAppliances);
                        $query->whereIn('brand_id',  $userBrands);
                        // $query->whereNotIn('id', $buyerPurchasedTicket);
                        $query->whereNotIn('brand_id', $buyerexcludedDevices);
                        $query->whereNotIn('zip_code_id', $buyerexcludedZipCode);
                    })
                    ->when($request->filters['brand_ids'], fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('brand_id', $request->filters['brand_ids']))
                    ->when($request->filters['appliance_ids'], fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('appliance_id', $request->filters['appliance_ids']))
                    ->when($request->filters['province_ids'], fn ($q) => $q->whereIn('province_id', $request->filters['province_ids']))
                    ->when($request->price, fn ($q) => $q->whereBetween('price', [$request->min_price, $request->max_price]))
                    
                    ->orderBy('tickets.created_at', $request->order ?? 'desc')
                    ->groupBy('ticket_statuses.status_id')
                    ->paginate($request->rows ?? 30)
                )
            ->response()->getData(true);
```

When I run the above code I get the following error

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'project.tickets.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from (select `tickets`.* from `tickets` inner join `ticket_statuses` on `tickets`.`id` = `ticket_statuses`.`ticket_id` where exists (select * from `ticket_statuses` inner join (select MAX(`ticket_statuses`.`id`) as `id_aggregate`, `ticket_statuses`.`ticket_id` from `ticket_statuses` group by `ticket_statuses`.`ticket_id`) as `latestOfMany` on `latestOfMany`.`id_aggregate` = `ticket_statuses`.`id` and `latestOfMany`.`ticket_id` = `ticket_statuses`.`ticket_id` where `tickets`.`id` = `ticket_statuses`.`ticket_id` and `status_id` in (1, 2)) and (`appliance_id` in (1, 2, 3) and `brand_id` in (1, 2, 3) and 1 = 1 and 1 = 1) group by `ticket_statuses`.`status_id`) as `aggregate_table`)"

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL query, your select list must only contains columns that are either appeared in the **GROUP BY** clause or aggregated columns.

MySQL enables `STRICT` mode by default, because there would be many weird cases happened without it. See an explanation of the `STRICT` mode [here](https://blog.jooq.org/use-mysqls-strict-mode-on-all-new-projects/).